# Tap, instead of click, the home button to go to home screen

Tags: iphone, settings

I am new to iPhone, and I am wondering if there is an option to only tap the home button to go to the home screen, instead of clicking it? Essentially the same as the "Rest finger to open" option, under "Accessibility > Home button", except I would want to use it for going to the home screen when the phone is already unlocked, instead of for unlocking it.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible without jailbreaking. Apple does not provide any mechanism for using a Touch ID tap for pressing the home button.

If the device is jailbroken, you can use one of the following options:

- Install [Activator 1.9.11 beta 2](http://rpetri.ch/cydia/activator/beta/) which has support for the ‘Single Press’ Touch ID event. This event can be mapped to ‘Home Button’, such that ‘touch fingerprint sensor once’ will ‘simulate a press of the home button’.
- Install [VirtualHome](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.w00tylab.virtualhome8/). This uses Touch ID events as home button presses, supporting single tap, double tap and hold, corresponding to their relevant events as if the button had been pressed.